# Javafx polyline

Tags: javafx, polyline

In my JavaFX project I have to draw basic line with MouseEvent, I chose to do it with Polyline, but it is not working porperly. Can't find the problem, here is the MouseEvent code:

```
if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
    Polyline line = new Polyline();
    main.getChildren().add(line);
    line.getPoints().add(event.getX());
    line.getPoints().add(event.getY());
    line.setScaleX(0);
    line.setScaleY(0);
    line.setStroke(Color.CORAL);
    line.setStrokeWidth(4);
} else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        Polyline line = new Polyline();
        for (Node s: main.getChildren()) {
            if (s instanceof Polyline) {
                line.getPoints().add(event.getX());
                line.getPoints().add(event.getY());
            }
        }
        main.getChildren().add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you expect this code to do, and what it is doing that is different from that. (It appears to be adding points on each drag to all the polylines in some container.) It might also help to show what this event handler is attached to, and how.

Comment: @James_D This code should draw line instead of these points. `EventHandler<MouseEvent> myHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {`

Answer (score 1):

It can't work cause each time the mouse event is called you create a new PolyLine object. You need to create one single PolyLine at the beginning and add all your points to this PolyLine. With your code is each point a new PolyLine. Btw. I'm not sure if adding the x and the y coordinate separate works well, try to use:

```
line.getPoints().addAll(event.getX(),event.getY());
```

Hope this helps :)